# dataType : "json", // <-- стоит ли указывать данное условие

Tags: jquery, json

К примеру есть такой код:

```
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/message_handler.php",
            dataType : "json", // <-- стоит ли указывать данное условие
            data: ({
                send_comment: c,
                send_reciver_id: b
            }),
            beforeSend: function () {
                $("#im_send").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                $("#messInput").val('')
            },
            success: function (d) {
                alert(d)
                $("#im_send").removeAttr("disabled")
            }
        })
```

Есть ли смысл указывать "dataType : "json", если в ответ придет массив? какие + и - есть у "dataType : "json" ?

Comment: что за + и -? какой массив придет в ответ? вы о чем вообще?

Comment: советую немедленно ознакомится с тем что такое ajax и каким боком получилось так что dataType можно указать не только json. На крайний случай у jquery есть вполне отличная документация

Answer (score 2):

Так это же [**JSON**](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/)!

Comment: мне понравилась ссылка